# How do I accept an answer -- where do I click?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

What do I have to do to accept an answer? I've looked through all the related questions. Only one even mentions anything about what to click to accept an answer, and that refers to a "check mark" symbol that I don't see anywhere. Where is a clear user guide reference on how to accept an answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can only accept answers on questions you have asked.  Next to each question, under the up and downvote arrows, there is a check mark.  It looks like this:

[image]

If you click the check mark, the question will be accepted.  Click it again to unaccept it.

Comment: More like +1 for overachievement.

Comment: Yes, including an image helped!

Answer (score 2):

It's to the left from answer, under the vote count.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the check mark next to an answer. It should then turn green (or some other color depending on the site's overall color scheme?).

Answer (score 1):

You should see the outline of a "tick" under the up & down vote arrows on each answer.  Click it for the answer you want to accept (and gain 2 rep for doing it).

Answer (score 0):

If some people can't see how to do it without asking, perhaps the interface needs redesigning.

Maybe some help text somewhere directly on your question (obviously only visible to the question author) to say that you should mark an answer and how to do it.

It might also help with the number of questions that seem never have an answer accepted even if there is a perfectly good one.

Comment: most typically unregistered users leave unaccepted answers. interface is **very** intuitive, I'm surprised to see that someone is not capable of finding a check mark.

Comment: You already get a reminder to accept an answer or set a bounty for questions over X days old (where X is a number I can't remember right now) - but it doesn't go that extra mile and remind you where the tick is.

Comment: I wonder - is a check mark "the universal symbol for yes"?

Comment: why would you need a "universal symbol"?

Comment: So that everyone can see at a glance what the symbol means.

Comment: Part of the problem is that most of the English speaking world calls it a tick, not a check (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_%28check_mark%29).

Comment: Check is American English AFAIK... The question whether it is part of *English speaking world* is left to the reader :-)