# Where can I thank contributors to StackOverflow?

Tags: support, appreciation

Actually, I would like to thank StackOverflow for providing great Q&A site.

But I don't know where to say thanks or to whom to say thanks.

Let me explain why I would like to thank StackOverflow:

- I am a newbie in iPhone development.
- Whatever I learned about the iPhone through surfing on Google & different forums was not enough to get solution to my queries.
- StackOverflow is a Q & A site, which has been the best Help for me.
- I can get all of the solutions of my problems from unknown people.
- I would like to thank all those people who helped me, because right now even my seniors don't try to help me. Whatever StackOverflow and all of its members are doing for me is like taking help from family members.
- I found only the site " StackOverflow " managing the information properly. Like No Repeat ( if it is then closed )
- Even user gives repeated link as helen just given below my question
- No abuse words Only Information
- No invalid discussions like forums - just Straight forward information

  - I am proud to be a member of StackOverflow.
  - I've learned the most from members of StackOverflow.

But, I don't know how to say thanks to those who helped me! How can I do this?

Comment: Even they understand what I mean to say & they correct my english. Like English Teacher.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-thanking-users-who-answered-my-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/when-someone-answers-my-question-correctly-and-completely-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the checkmark and upvote buttons instead.

Answer (score 9):

Start answering questions for others who need the knowledge that you have gained.  That's what it's all about.

Comment: Really? And here I was thinking it was the hokey-pokey. Dammit all to hell, I've gotten it all wrong yet again.

Comment: Sir ! I yet not believe myself to confident to give answer. When I will be, I will do my best for StackOverFlow & to all their members.

Comment: @sagar: Really? I hit my repcap off of this question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351925 -- It's just proof that there *are* easy questions out there waiting for you to answer them! Find your niche and start answering questions. You'll find yourself getting lots and lots better as time goes on.

Comment: @sagar --  my feeling is that you learn more by answering than by asking.  Even if your answer comes in way late and never gets any upvotes, you'll benefit by answering.  I also agree with @Eric.  Jump in with both feet; you know more than you think you do.

Comment: @Eric - I have to admit that question is one of the times I wish we could download comments.